# Code formatting hints necessary?

Tags: discussion, design, asking-questions

I was About to ask my first Question on this side when i saw the Code formatting tips on the right (yellow area). I am very new to this site, but i am Pretty sure there should be very few Questions which include Code, if any at all!?

[image]

I am a bit surprised i didnt find the Question, the closest match i found was this: [Do code backticks really have a use on this site?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3941/do-code-backticks-really-have-a-use-on-this-site). I hope i didnt oversee a post.

Comment: You are right, that question you linked is the one where the consensus was to not use code formatting (use quote blocks instead)... That what you see is the standard info on using the format style of SE network (how to use italics, code blocks, etc.). Are you asking if hinting how to use code formatting should not be done?

Comment: yes or would it be too much effort to exclude it for certain sides only?

Comment: I don't know about that but I suspect that anything that is customized style will present additional work and procedures to the devs and SE backend. But, precisely that is what this post will help find out :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that help is the same on all sites.  I just saw it on Pets (!).  The language-designation stuff is especially egregious on non-programming sites.  I wonder if it can be changed on a per-site basis.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Probably worth asking on Meta. I think there would be a lot of support from the non-programming sites, especially if the problems with code markup and screen-readers are explained.